# What practices should be used when writing a JPA repository

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a spring rest application, the problem is that I am not sure while I should use a `repository` or when a `service` interface together with `implementation` of it. Let's say that I have a repository that has a method `findById` I created a service interface that has the same method it returns the object and is called `Object findById(Long id);` and I wonder if I should create an implementation of that that's looks like that

```
public Object findById(Long id) {
    repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("message"));
}
```

but I could also do the same without this service class as the repository also returns a Optional so it could be also done in the controller

```
repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("message"));
```

But it's hard to test repositories, better is to create an implementation of the service and then test the service. Anyway what's yours opinion about it, which one is better for you and why?

Comment: I would prefer repository to just return value if it found or not,  and then throw the exception in service class. because tomorrow you might get requirement to get value by `id` or else do nothing

Comment: @Deadpool I am not sure if I get it, could you please provide below a simple example of it using the above example?

Answer (score -1):

I think it's all about your project architecture. one of the classic, simplest and most favorite architectures is `N-Layer` architecture which normally is implemented with 3 main layers. `Controllers`, `Services` and `Repositories`.

`Controllers` are responsible for getting the requests from clients, updating the model usually with calling `Services` and returning a response for clients.

`Services` are where your business logic are implemented and where you should usually check for your transaction management and some security checking and etc.

and finally `Repositories` are where you interact with underlying systems like `File System` and  `Database` to save the state of your application.